# Change iframe target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am totally new in JS, resp. I am trying to do something I am not familiar with, but that´s the way I learn things. I am coding html website and I used an iframe element. In this iframe I´d like to show different htmls (on click). So I read some other questions including this one: [stackoverflow js iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229245/javascript-function-in-iframe-src) and I made this code:

```
<li><p id="video" class="button"><a target="iframe">VIDEO</a></p></li>
<li><p id="kontakt" class="button"><a target="iframe">KONTAKT</a></p></li>

<li><iframe width="800px" height="1000px" frameBorder="0" name="iframe" src=""></iframe></li>

<script>
    $(".button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("underline");
    $(".button").not(this).removeClass("underline")
    }); 
</script>

<script>
$("#video").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]').src = "video_iframe.html"
}); 
</script>

<script>
$("#kontakt").on("click", function() {
$('[name="iframe"]').src = "kontakt_iframe.html"
}); 
</script>
```

But unfortunately it´s not working. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('[name="iframe"]')` is a jQuery object - to access the `src` property you need to reference the actual native DOM element.

```
$('[name="iframe"]')[0].src = "kontakt_iframe.html";
```

Also - you dont need multiple `script` tags - just use one and put your code in there.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

`$('[name="iframe"]').src = "video_iframe.html"`

to

`$('[name="iframe"]').attr('src', 'video_iframe.html')`

This sets the attribute of `src` to the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use so many times script tags. If you are using jQuery click event then there is no need to have `<a target="iframe">`. Try rather this:

```
<li><p id="video" class="button">VIDEO</p></li>
<li><p id="kontakt" class="button">KONTAKT</p></li>

<li><iframe width="800px" height="1000px" frameBorder="0" name="iframe" src=""> </iframe></li>

<script>
$(".button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("underline");
    $(".button").not(this).removeClass("underline")
}); 


$("#video").on("click", function() {
    $('iframe').attr("src","video_iframe.html") 
}); 


$("#kontakt").on("click", function() {
    $('iframe').attr("src", "kontakt_iframe.html") 
}); 
</script>
```