# Angular - Dynamically loading an image

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-2.0

### I've searched all over StackOverflow but I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem.

---

### **F.Y.I I'm using ASP.net Core 2.0's default angular project**

I'm currently building an Angular application where I'm trying to load in a customer's logo based on a config found elsewhere.

I'm trying to load this file into my home.component.html

I created a "CustomerService" which has a function getLogo() which in itself returns the customer's logo's path.

My folder structure is as follows:
[FOLDER STRUCTURE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAdmP.png)

The **assets** folder holds the images, and the HTML found below is found in **home.component.html**

I know that **"../../"** isn't the way to go, so my first question is how I'd be able to fix that.

I've created the following HTML structure:

```
<img src="../../assets/timeblockr-logo.png" />
<img [src]="customerservice.getLogo()" />
```

And the CustomerService's getLogo function returns the following:

```
getLogo() {
    return "../../assets/timeblockr-logo.png";
}
```

---

### ** EDIT: FOUND THE SOLUTION!!! **

Turns out I had to use:

```
getLogo(): string{
    return require("../assets/timeblockr-logo.png");
}
```

**Special thanks to @Niladri for the solution to this issue!**

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196435/javascript-function-return-src-path).

Comment: Where is your index.html file located ? the path of the image is relative to the location of index.html inside dist folder if you have added it to angular-cli.json

Comment: @Niladri My index.cshtml file is located in the **Views/home** folder

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork are you using .NET core 2.0?

Comment: @Niladri, Yes I am, as stated in the beginning of the post and also in the tags :)

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork what is the current path of image being displayed in html? can you share your webpack.config.* js files including the vendor

Comment: @Niladri Regarding the path to the images, it shows **dist/a0eeffbba7398daebf178f3d7fab50eb.png** I'll add the web pack config files to the post.

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork do you have that image in dist folder after build ? did you check it?

Comment: @Niladri Yup, but only when using both image tags.
The first one works, and gets added to the dist folder.
But the second img tag doesn't get the updated src from webpack.

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork in ts file update the URL as this inside getLogo method `const ImageUrl:string = require("../../assets/timeblockr-logo.png"); return ImageUrl;`

Comment: @Niladri Result of that: **Error: Cannot find module "../../assets/timeblockr-logo.png"**

Comment: @Niladri Changed the structure to **require("../assets/timeblockr-logo.png")** and it works THANKS!

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork great should I post this as answer with explanation?

Comment: @Niladri Yes please, I'll mark it as the solution :)

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork Ok it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack uses `url-loader` to load images from your angular project that comes with extension `.png,.jpg` etc . Take a look at the below code from the `url-loader` repo in github https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

it looks for image files with the above extensions. But we need to use `require` statement to the actual image path for the Webpack to understand the path of the image so that it can pick them up. This is required in `.ts` / typescript files while using the path of the image as a variable or returning the path value from a method . The first image tag

`<img src="../../assets/timeblockr-logo.png" />` was working because Webpack uses `html-loader` for `.html` files, which automatically replaces src attribute values on image tags with the bundled image URL.

So your `getLogo()` method should be like below

```
getLogo():string {
    return require("../assets/timeblockr-logo.png");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your image source should be without **`../../`**. The image paths are relative in the output folder. Just change to this:

```
<img src="assets/timeblockr-logo.png" />
<img [src]="customerservice.getLogo()" />
```

And your function should be:

```
getLogo(): string {
    return "assets/timeblockr-logo.png";
}
```

As per your comments, you need to change your **`"assets"`** entry in **`.angular-cli.json`** to this:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    { 
        "glob": "**/*", 
        "input": "./assets/images/", 
        "output": "./assets/images/", 
        "allowOutsideOutDir": false 
    }
],
```

Comment: This results in **localhost:56982/assets/timeblockr-logo.png 404 (Not Found**) it seems like webpack doesn't update this url. because I also added the other image include (which does work) and it's SRC is changed to **dist/a0eeffbba7398daebf178f3d7fab50eb.png**

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork can you post your folder structure? are you using angular-cli?

Comment: Hey @Niladri , Folder structure is already in the post ;)
I'm using ASP.net Core's default angular project.

Comment: @Rick-HashtagNetwork can you post your angular-cli.json file

Comment: @Niladri added to the post! :)

Comment: @Faisal Unfortunately, this didn't do anything.

Comment: @Faisal I copy and pasted all of your changes, including the string indication etc. But I'm still getting errors: [SCREENSHOT](https://imgur.com/a/TsjX8)

Comment: @Faisal Also in this manner, the previously working image include isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<img [src]="customerservice.getLogo()" />`

To `<img [attr.src]="customerservice.getLogo()" />`

Read more about [Attribute Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding).

Comment: This results in  **http://localhost:56982/assets/timeblockr-logo.png 404 (Not Found)** it seems like webpack doesn't update this url. because I also added the other image include (which does work) and it's SRC is changed to **dist/a0eeffbba7398daebf178f3d7fab50eb.png**

Comment: @TomaszKula , `<img [src]="customerservice.getLogo()" />` is also correct way to specify the source.