# Passing Variable to html embedded URL

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I would like to pass a variable from which I can build a URL link and then would like to embed the link in html. I tried doing the following:

```
<div class="main">
  <h2>Test App</h2>
  <iframe id=my_url src="myFunction()" width="900" height="1300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("my_url ").src = "www.google.com";
    }
  </script>
```

I eventually want to be able to get a variable from a flask app and create a URL and set it equal to document.getElementById("my_url ").src. But in the meantime, when I run this code I get a "404 Page Not Found" error. What am I doing wrong in the above example?

Thanks!

Comment: the answer to that is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12196479/6328225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is:

1- id=my_url > it should be id="my_url" with the qoutes or double quotes

2- src="myFunction()" > you are setting your src to myFunction(), this wont triger the function

3- getElementById("my_url ") > it should be getElementById("my_url") without the space

4- "www.google.com" > you need to set src to a valid link, you need to add the protocol

here is the code and good luck:

```js
<div class="main">
        <h2>Test App</h2>
        <iframe id="my_url" width="900" height="1300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("my_url").src = "https://www.google.com";
        }
        myFunction()
</script>
```

Comment: I wanted to pass a variable from flask to the url to build the url. Let's say the variable is called x. I thought I could do document.getElementById("my_url").src = " https://www." + {x} + ".com" and have x = google, for example. But this fails. Did I miss something? Usually when I pass a variable I have to put it in {{x}} to have it display the html but I don't think that works here either. Thanks!

Comment: try this      document.getElementById("my_url").src = "https://www." + {{x}} + ".com"

Comment: I was able to find a workaround by constructing the whole URL on the flask side and passing that to the html side. thanks!